# Copying offsets from screen to string asm 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to create a file editor that basically coping the text from a file to the screen edit it and copying the offsets from the screen back to the file.

Any ideas and codes about hole those steps will be wonderful especially about the last one, I'm using asm 8086 16 bit

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is what OS you are using. For example say you are using MS-DOS then to read a file from disk the method is to populate the filename into a memory address and then initiate the operation using a software interrupt. However if you were using something like MINIX then it would you would still populate the filename into memory but the file open operation for some versions of MINIX would put a value in AX and the call a specific software interrupt. There simply is not enough data to help you.

Comment: I'm using dosbox